# C# Implementing Dispose - why need check disposing and disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, idisposable

I searched and did not find the exact answer. I'm learning the correct way of [Implementing Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx). I am wondering why need the 2 bools.

1. Why need **disposing**? Only the destructor calls Dispose (false), so why destructor not force release managed resources?
2. Why need **disposed**? If this object is already disposed, how could the Dispose method be called? Could you tell a scenario when the Dispose is called and disposed is true?

Comment: have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface/538238#538238 ?

Comment: @Shazi thanks, I'll read it in detail.

Comment: If the *disposing* argument is false then the object was not disposed.  It is the finalizer (aka destructor) that ran.  That matters a lot, it means that you cannot dispose any objects stored in fields, they might have already been finalized.  You need *disposed* for safety, client code may call Dispose more than once.  Writing your own finalizer and implementing the disposable pattern has a very desirable trait, it is wrong 99.9% of the time.  Framework classes need to do this, not you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question: the `Dispose()` method should be callable twice without problems (see [`IDisposable.Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx):

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one.The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times.Instance methods other than Dispose can throw an ObjectDisposedException when resources are already disposed.

A common case is when a `Stream` object is passed to another `Stream` object that takes "ownership":

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    //using (var sw = new StreamWriter(zip, Encoding.UTF8, 4096, true))
    {

    }

    // false: ms has already been disposed
    bool canWrite = ms.CanWrite;
}
```

The `StreamWriter` normally takes ownership on the underlying stream (in this case `ms`), so that when the `Dispose()` of the `StreamWriter` is called so is the `Dispose()` of the `MemoryStream`... But note that even the `MemoryStream` is in a `using` block, so its `Dispose()` will be called again.

There is no problem here, because the `Dispose()` of the various `Stream` classes are correctly implemented. If you want to avoid this double `Dispose()`, nearly all the `Stream` classes have an overload that tells them if they must take ownership on the underlying `Stream` (see the commented row... The argument is called `leaveOpen`, so by setting it to `true` the `StreamWriter` won't `Dispose()` the underlying stream)

Answer (score 1):

The `disposing` boolean is there to indicate where `Dispose` was called from. Was it explicitly called via `YourObject.Dispose` or a `using` statement, or was it implicitly called from the finalizer thread.

This differentiation is needed because when `Dispose` is ran from the finalizer thread, there is no guarantee that any managed objects are still alive in object, thus restricting dispose only to to unmanaged resources owned by the type.

The `disposed` boolean is there to flag that the object has already been disposed. Say, for example, one does dispose the object, but the implementation lacks `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`. Even though the object is disposed, it would still run (again) once it's finalizer executes, and attempt to free those unmanaged resources again, where they have already been released.

The example in the documentation you provided explains this nicely:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Free other state (managed objects).
        }

        // Free your own state (unmanaged objects).
        // Set large fields to null.
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about **disposed**,seems you did not mention yet.